# Cassandra CQL INSERT query rejected for unconfigured column family

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql, datastax

I'm trying to insert some rows into a Cassandra (1.2.16) database with CQL, but the Datastax API call is being rejected. The query is created through a `PreparedStatement` and executed with a `BoundStatement` like so

```
session.Execute (boundStatement); 
// query is
INSERT INTO "KeyspaceName.ColumnFamilyName" (key, column1, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

It gets rejected with

```
Caught an exception Cassandra.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily KeyspaceName.ColumnFamilyName
// which happens at the Execute call above
```

However, I can see that the column family does exist

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder ()
    .AddContactPoint ("127.0.0.1")
    .Build ();

new List<string> (cluster.Metadata.GetKeyspaces ()).ForEach ((value) => {
    Console.WriteLine ("Keyspace: " + value);

    new List<string> (cluster.Metadata.GetKeyspace(value).GetTablesNames()).ForEach((tableName) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Table: " + tableName);
    });
});
```

which prints (among others)

```
Keyspace: KeyspaceName
Table: ColumnFamilyName
```

So the column family is there.

Why can't Cassandra find the table/column family when executing the CQL `INSERT` query? Is this a version issue? I'm under the impression that newer versions of CQL refer to column families as tables. How should I configure the table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception basically means you haven't created that column family. You can retrieve it however the exception is telling you its looking for a cf named `KeyspaceName.ColumnFamilyName`. You have to have "KeyspaceName" and "ColumnFamilyName" in separate quotation marks, otherwise the parser will think you are only supplying a name for a column family. It will see your query as, *I want to insert data into a column family of name "KeyspaceName.ColumnFamilyName"*, so try:

```
INSERT INTO "KeyspaceName"."ColumnFamilyName" (key, column1, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
                         ^ ^
                         | 
                         This is where the magic happens!
```

Comment: The added `"` worked. Is the keyspace name required? Can it just be `INSERT INTO ColumnFamilyName ...` since the `Session` was created from the keyspace name? It didn't seem to work when I tried it.

Comment: Yeah, without quotes, it gives `unconfigured columnfamily columnfamilyname`. I guess that's part of the spec. Note that it does work with quotes but without keyspace name `INSERT INTO "ColumnFamilyName"`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yep, it can be just the cf name but you'll have to use the particular ks via the C# driver's `sessionObj.ChangeKeyspace("KeyspaceName");`

Comment: Cool. In my case, I don't need to change keyspace since I acquired it through `Cluster#Connect(keyspaceName)`. Thanks!